# Android: SafetyNet Attest Device Verification Response Network Error

Tags: android, safetynet

I'm calling SafetyNet Api using Google Client but it not responding the correct response.

```
   SafetyNet.SafetyNetApi.attest(mGoogleApiClient, generateNonce())
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<SafetyNetApi.AttestationResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(SafetyNetApi.AttestationResult result) {
                    Status status = result.getStatus();
                    String data = decodeJws(result.getJwsResult());

                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        // Indicates communication with the service was successful.
                        // Use result.getJwsResult() to get the result data.
                    } else {
                        // An error occurred while communicating with the service.
                    }
                }
            });
```

I'm getting below error message in result method.

Status{statusCode=NETWORK_ERROR, resolution=null}

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because you are using [`SafetyNetApi`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/safetynet/SafetyNetApi), which is no longer supported.

Starting with Google Play Services 11.0.0, you should now [get an API key](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation.html#add-api-key), and use [`SafetyNetClient`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/safetynet/SafetyNetClient) instead.

You may also want to take a look at [10 things you might be doing wrong when using the SafetyNet Attestation API](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/10-things-you-might-be-doing-wrong-when.html).

Answer (score 0):

First you have to generate nonce by following method

```
   private static byte[] getRequestNonce() {
    String data = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[24];
    Random random = new Random();
    random.nextBytes(bytes);
    try {
        byteStream.write(bytes);
        byteStream.write(data.getBytes());
    }catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return byteStream.toByteArray();
}
```

Afterwords use safety net client attestation api

```
 SafetyNet.getClient(context).attest(nonce, <API KEY>).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<SafetyNetApi.AttestationResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(SafetyNetApi.AttestationResponse attestationResponse) {
                    // parse response 

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    // An error occurred while communicating with the service.
                }
            });
        }
```

Reference: [Sample Code Offline verification](https://github.com/dishantwalia/ClientSideDeviceVerification)

[Sample Code Online verification using google api](https://github.com/dishantwalia/SafetyNetCheckDemo/tree/master/SafetyNetDemo)